# How to write my own custom compression logic in apache server

Tags: java, apache, jsp, web

Im doing some project for compressing the web traffic, that is the data send from server to browser.
So like other http compression techniques like gzip or sdcp, i want to compress the data before sending it from server. But i have no idea about writing such a module in apache.
Can any one guide me?

I have written a proxy server at the browser side which decompress the data compressed by my logic.

Comment: Sounds like it could be proto buffer: http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html

Comment: Apache is a big software company. What server product specifically are you talking about? Apache HTTPD or Apache Tomcat? You've a `jsp` tag which suggests it to be Apache Tomcat. Regardless, both servers have a simple configuration setting to turn compression on without the need to write any code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Compress it in a servlet filter and stream it back, but... really? Your compression is better/faster/etc. than standard gzip? Is it *enough* faster to want to bother?

Comment: But will it process all the reponses or only a single project.
As per my scenario, the module must alter all the response from the server. Not a specific project.

GZip is great. But the data compressed by my algorithm can be again compressed using gzip.

Comment: @user840629 Then I'm not convinced that the second compression will yield enough benefit to be worth it, but who knows. In any case, a filter is for a single app, by definition. Still don't know if you're talking about Tomcat, httpd, etc. but [TC7 supports server-wide filters, apparently](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html).

Comment: It yelid better result in some scenarios.